# Does Debug formatter use dereference?

Tags: rust

I am confused about how does the Debug formatter get to the end of the reference chain.

My understanding is that `println!("{:?}", x)` expands to something like:

```
... print(&x) ...
```

which borrows `x` instead of moving/copying it.

Now this prints `MyNumber(1)` instead of expected `&MyNumber(1)`:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyNumber(u8);

fn main() {
    let x = MyNumber(1);
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

from which I assume that the Debug formatter follows the generic `Deref` implementation defined for all references by the Rust language itself (`impl<T> Deref for &T`).

If so, then why the following code prints `MyNumber(1)` instead of just `1`?

```
use std::ops::{Deref};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyNumber(u8);

impl Deref for MyNumber {
    type Target = u8;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = MyNumber(1);
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

It seems to me that the Debug formatter follows the `Deref` implemented on `&T` by the Rust language itself but ignores the `Deref` implemented on my custom type.

Does anyone know why this happens? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this happens? Any help much appreciated!

If you check [the documentation for Debug](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) then search around [you will find](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html#impl-Debug-192):

```rust
impl<'_, T> Debug for &'_ T where
    T: Debug + ?Sized,
```

Meaning there is a bulk-implementation specifically on references which delegates to the underlying object. Which in your case is `MyNumber`, at which point that's what's used.

There is no implementation for `Deref`, instead there are implementations for each smart pointer type (if you search in the page you'll find implementations for `Box` and `Rc`).

So your code prints `MyNumber(1)` because that's what it's told to do: it invokes the `Debug` implementation on `MyNumber`. If you want something different, you need to implement (not derive) `Debug` to delegate to its underlying type.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I incorrectly assumed that there's somehow involved a recursive deref. After reading the referenced docs and the actual implementation, I can say that delegating to the underlying "debuggable" seems much more elegant. I like Rust more and more!